# Craftsman Screw Drive Garage Door opens too far

Tags: garage-door-opener

How does the opener know when to stop when it's moving to the open position?

Have two openers 1 for each door; one works fine, the other opens too far and actually bangs into the actual opener housing.

On other openers I've had there has been a visible lever the opener hits to stop but none is apparent on this one.

Thank you!

Comment: Some of the doors have an adjustment pot that when turned 1/2 turn allows the door to travel 1 additional inch or 1 inch less I don't remember the direction but i think it was CCW to stop the door sooner.

Comment: See [page 23](http://www.liftmaster.com/catalogresourcesv3/en-us/shared/files/tucmanuals/114a3044.pdf). Your door may not be exactly the same, but ever opener on the planet has travel adjustment of one sort or another. Usually it's labeled fairly clearly.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a panel on the right side of your unit.  It will have 4 adjustments on it.  2 are for the force adjustment and 2 are to adjust the upper and lower limits.  They usually have a sticker to show you what each one does.